# What does __STDC_ISO_10646__ exactly mean?

Tags: c++, unicode

I'm having a hard time understanding the macro `__STDC_ISO_10646__`, from my copy of the C++ standard:

`__STDC_ISO_10646__`

> An integer constant of the form yyyymmL (for example, 199712L). If
>   this symbol is defined, then every character in the Unicode required
>   set, when stored in an object of type wchar_t, has the same value as
>   the short identifier of that character. The Unicode required set
>   consists of all the characters that are defined by ISO/IEC 10646,
>   along with all amendments and technical corrigenda as of the specified
>   year and month.

From my understanding, this means `wchar_t` on your system would represent a unicode code point. Is this correct? If this is the case, then utf-8 and utf-16 encoding would not be conforming and utf-32 would be conforming right?. Also, what other character encodings are conforming?

Comment: I don't know enough to say anything about other character sets, but why would UTF-32 not be conforming?

Comment: @hvd: I think I was wrong about utf-32, you are right, utf-32 would be conforming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section of the standard you quote (§16.8 Predefined macro names [cpp.predefined]) prefixes the series of definitions with:

> ¶2 The following macro names are conditionally defined by the implementation:

That means that if the implementation can't meet the requirements (e.g. because `wchar_t` is a 16-bit type), then the implementation will not define `__STDC_ISO_10646__`.

On the other hand, if `wchar_t` is a 32-bit or larger type, then the implementation may well be able to define the macro.  ISO 10646 only requires 21 bits to represent all the characters, but for (almost) all practical purposes, that means that 16-bit `wchar_t` is too small and 32-bit `wchar_t` is amply big enough.  It also means an implementation from scratch is likely to make `wchar_t` into a 32-bit type.  Pre-existing implementations may be hobbled by backwards compatibility if they chose a 16-bit `wchar_t` before this option was standardized.

Comment: Did ISO 10646 always requires 21 bits? I thought maybe earlier versions were only 16-bit, so theoretically an implementation could support an earlier version of ISO 10646.

Comment: No; ISO 10646 did not always require 21 bits. At some time in the previous millennium, it only required the 16-bits of what is now the BMP, Basic Multi-Lingual Plane.  But in the current millennium, it has always needed 21 bits (AFAICR — subject to correction by someone specifying a version number and release date).  However, some compilers have been around long enough that some features of their behaviour in the 1990s (e.g. `sizeof(wchar_t)`) has to be retained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: AFAICT, Unicode V2.0 from 1996 expanded the range of character codes to 21 bits.

Comment: You're right, quote from [here](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html): `starting with Unicode 2.0 (July, 1996), it has not been a 16-bit encoding.` although the supplementary planes (characters outside of the BMP) were added in ISO 10646-2 (2001) it seems. Thanks.

Comment: My understanding is that ISO 10646 (or at least its predecessor attempt at an ISO Universal Character Set) required 31 bits and its arrangement was completely incompatible with Unicode. However I don't think ISO **ever** had a 16-bit UCS. One of the points of contention with Unicode was that 16 bits was way too small, and I'm pretty sure that, by the time the UCS and Unicode resolved their differences and essentially merged, it was agreed that the character set would be larger than 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

The macro relates to the value of the unicode character when this is stored in wchar_t.

More specifically, ISO/IEC 10646 standard supports more characters as ammendments are made to the standard.

The year and month that you can define as a value to the macro mean that when you store a Unicode character to a wchar_t variable, then the value of the unicode character that will be stored in that variable will be the one that was in effect in the given year and month.

See here `[http://www.unicode.org/charts/][1]` for a reference of Unicode short identifiers

Hope this helps

Lefteris

Comment: I usually wait to allow other people to answer. Do you know if it is possible to define the macro with a 16-bit `wchar_t`?

Comment: This is an extract from Wikipedia on wide character [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) The standard library of the C programming language includes a lot of facilities for dealing with wide characters and strings composed of them. The wide characters are defined using datatype wchar_t, which in the original C90 standard was defined as 16-bit value due to historical compatibility reasons. C and C++ compilers that comply with the 10646-1:2000 Unicode standard generally assume 32-bit values.

Comment: From the same link... However, the ISO/IEC 10646:2003 Unicode standard 4.0 says that: "ANSI/ISO C leaves the semantics of the wide character set to the specific implementation but requires that the characters from the portable C execution set correspond to their wide character equivalents by zero extension."

Comment: @Lefteris "which in the original C90 standard was defined as 16-bit value" -- C has always allowed implementations with `CHAR_BIT` equal to, for example, 9, or 64, so `wchar_t` cannot ever have been required to be exactly 16 bits. Wikipedia is not a credible source. Do any of its references support this claim?

Comment: @JesseGood Looking at the manual of glibc available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extended-Char-Intro.html#Extended-Char-Intro), I read the following: "The ISO C90 standard, where wchar_t was introduced, does not say anything specific about the representation. It only requires that this type is capable of storing all elements of the basic character set.[...]

But in the GNU C Library wchar_t is always 32 bits wide and, therefore, capable of representing all UCS-4 values and, therefore, covering all of ISO 10646. [...]"

Comment: The good thing about wikipedia is that it can be edited. Edited.